# Query works on phpmyadmin but doesn't in PHP Zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, phpmyadmin

What seems to be the problem, i hope someone can point that out, thanks alot in advance

Here is the query:

```
SELECT employees . * , 
       departments.departmentid, 
       departments.namealias, 
       positions.reporttopositionid, 
       centres.name, 
       positions.pos_en, 
       jobs.titleid, 
       jobs.compensationlevelid 
FROM employees 
INNER JOIN hcmpositionworkerassignment wa 
       ON employees.worker_recid = wa.worker 
INNER JOIN positions ON wa.position = positions.recid 
INNER JOIN departments ON positions.department = departments.recid 
INNER JOIN centres ON positions.ilacenterid = centres.siteid 
INNER JOIN jobs ON positions.job = jobs.recid 
WHERE employees.ilacenterid = 'TC-HN1'
```

Comment: Please show how you make that query in zend.